# Upload video with compress on s3 server using php and codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg. It takes time to upload, as I first save the video to a folder on my server, then move it to an S3 bucket and then delete the video.

Is there any solution to upload and compress a video without saving to some location?

Comment: Not really. The video has to be uploaded to the server to be worked on. The upload time is entirely at the mercy of the client's upload connection speed

Comment: yes but its aproach is wrong i am uploading video 2 times first on server then on s3  but without compress when i upload it takes less time

Comment: Do you mean to upload the video directly to s3 without saving it locally on your server?

Comment: yes with use of compress video , suppose video is 25 mb then compress its size and quality upto 5-8 MB if possible , as same am doing with ffmpeg.

Comment: Have you considered a streaming server, such as Red5?

Comment: no @alokhttp://stackoverflow.com/users/3585071/alok